# learn 3d-models and recognize real world objects on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, opencv, object-detection

I do have multiple 3d-models in files (.igs, .stp, .x_t) and need to generate a (machine learning?) model out of them to recognize those objects in real world.

E.g. I do have exact 3d-drawings of different keys, now I need to recognize those keys in a video on the mobile device (doesn't matter if Android or iOS). I looked into OpenCV with its edge detection as well as generating thousands of images out of the 3d-file, but both ways didn't lead anywhere. Do tools exist that allow this kind of object recognition?

Comment: It is a good idea to provide any source of visual input like a image of these 3d drawing.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't as it's private information... what kind of information do you need out of the drawing? Imagine some kind of object which will appear exactly in this form in real world, e.g. a specific toy, key, lego stone, ...

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve